# Ajuda com relacionamentos #rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho 3 tabelas

> **area** 
>  name
>
> **area_shared** 
>  area_id 
>  request_id
>
> **request**
>  area_shared_id 
>  area_id

Eu gostaria de exibir minha tabela dessa maneira <%=@request.area_shared.area_name%>

porém acho que meus relacionamentos estão errados, alguém pode me ajudar?

Obs: Lembrando que dentro do form request tenho um fields_for com area_shared que funciona, o problema é somente para exibir mesmo.

Comment: Como está o teu relacionamento actualmente? podes mostrar o código?

Answer (score 0):

Pra que seja possível chamar @request.area_shared você precisa de uma relação 1(request) para 1(area_shared). O mesmo de area_shared para area se é isso que você quer.(@request.area_shared.area.name)

**area** 
name #belongs_to :area_shared
area_shared_id

**area_shared** 
request_id #belongs_to :request
           #has_one :area

**request** #has_one :area_shared

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria assim:

```
class Area < ...
    has_many :shared_areas
end
```

e...

```
class Request < ...
    belongs_to :shared_areas
end
```

e...

```
class SharedArea < ...
    belongs_to :area
    has_many :requests
end
```

Com isso, eu poderia fazer:

```
<%= @request.shared_area.area.name %>
```

De qualquer forma, mostra como está o teu código para que eu possa melhorar a minha resposta. Mas pelo que entendi, é disso que precisas.